# change data source after zooming - core plot

Tags: plot, core-plot

I need to change the data source after zooming my plot, can I intercept in some way when zooming is finished?

I set the allowsUserInteraction=YES and so I can panning and zooming but I don't find the method for handle this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the correct methods:

```
- (BOOL) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (BOOL) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point 
- (BOOL) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
- (BOOL) plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint
```

Comment: can u elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the plot ranges with a plot space delegate. When the ranges meet whatever threshold you set, change the datasource.

Comment: Yes, at the end I find delegate methods and I use it, now i'm out, this night I add an answer with solution.